# Usage of mysqlconnection in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently building a Windows Form App project, in which each form needs to have access to the common database. Which of the following method is better:
(1) Build a separate `MySqlConnection` for each form
(2) Build only one single common `MySqlConnection` for the entire project. In other words, all the forms share the same `MySqlConnection`.
My application requires frequent operations on database... I'm afraid that it will ocuupy a bit long time to build the connection every time I am using a new `MySqlConnection` in `using` block. Therefore, I wonder if there is a universal standard when the application needs frequent read/write requests on the database.

Comment: (3) Use a new `MySqlConnection` each time you need to run a query or related group of queries.

Comment: It doesn't matter which specific provider you use. As all examples and tutorials show, including Connector/Net tutorials, connections should be short-lived and declared in `using` blocks. Locks are active until a connection closes which means that long-lived connections *increase* blocking and the chance of deadlocks

Comment: *"I'm afraid that it will ocuupy a bit long time to build the connection..."* - There's a connection pool that takes care of that problem. Connection objects and socket connections are not the same thing. The provider (you should use MySqlConnector, not MySql.Data) will map connection objects to pooled socket connections for you. Unless you see some *actual* performance problems that you can objectively trace to establishing connections, you shouldn't be concerned with this.